# IEEE-formatted bib entries along with authoryear-style citation call-outs?

Tags: citing

How does one get citation call-outs of the form `(Lastname, year)` using IEEEtran in LaTeX? Right now it gives me `(1)`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Please provide a compilable document together with your `.bib` file.

Answer (score 1):

To get IEEEtran-formatted bibliographic entries along with authoryear-style citation call-outs, I suggest you load the `natbib` citation management package and employ the `IEEEtranN` bibliography style. (Hint: The "`N`" in `IEEEtranN` stands for `natbib`.) Then use `\citet` and `\citep` to generate text-style and parenthesis-style citation call-outs.

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@misc{aa:3001,
  author = "Anne Author", title = "Thoughts", year = 3001,
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{natbib}
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtranN}

\begin{document}
\noindent
\citet{aa:3001} \quad \citep{aa:3001}
\bibliography{mybib}
\end{document}
```